# error: no match for ‘operator<’ when I stream to cout

Tags: c++

I am creating a Matrix class, and I am overloading all of the basic operators. For instance:

```
class Matrix {
    Matrix operator<(const float& ); // returns a Matrix with
                                     // entries 0 or 1 based on
                                     // whether the element is less than
                                     // what's passed in.


};
```

I also wrote a streaming operator:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream&cout,const Matrix &M){
    for(int i=0;i<M.rows;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<M.columns;++j) {
            cout<<M.array[i][j]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return cout;
}
```

However, when I try to use these:

```
int main() {
     Matrix M1;
     cout << M1 < 5.8;
}
```

I get this error:

> error: no match for ‘`operator<`’ in ‘`operator<<((* & std::cout), (*(const Matrix*)(& m))) < 5.7999999999999998e+0`’

What does this error mean?

Comment: `cout << (M < 5.8);`

Answer (score 6):

The left-streaming operator `<<` has higher precedence than the comparison operator `<`.

So...

`cout << M1 < 5.8`

is equivalent to

`(cout << M1) < 5.8`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

---

PS. This behavior is *dumb* but we're stuck with it for historical reasons.  The original intention of the `<<` was to be a mathematical operation (where this precedence makes sense), not streaming.

Comment: Calling it like `cout << (M1 < 5.8)` works right?  That should override the default behavior.

Comment: Or equivalently, `operator<<(cout, M1 < 5.8)`

Comment: Who's dumb decision was it to make the left shift operator a way to write to streams?

Comment: I really liked `operator<<` when I first came to C++, but nowadays I really wish the convention was like Java's `ToString()` or python's `__str__`.  It's good to understand that back in C we didn't have *any* way to just say "Print this object".  Besides, calling it explicitly (`operator<<(a, b)`) is perfectly acceptable IMO.